# Unable to successfully setup TLS on a Multi-Tenant GKE+Istio with LetsEncrypt (via Cert Manager)

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, istio, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I'm trying configure for TLS (LetsEncrypt) on a multi-tenant GKE+Istio setup.

I mainly followed this guide -> [Full Isolation in Multi-Tenant SAAS with Kubernetes & Istio](https://www.slideshare.net/DevOpsIndonesia/full-isolation-in-multitenant-saas-with-kubernetes-istio) for setting up the multi-tenancy in GKE+Istio, which I was able to successfully pull-off. I'm able to deploy simple apps on their separate namespaces which are accessible through their respective subdomains.

I then tried to move forward and setup the TLS with LetsEncrypt. For this I mainly followed a different guide which is can be found here-> [istio-gke](https://github.com/stefanprodan/istio-gke) . But unfortunately, following this guide didn't produce the result I wanted. When I was done with it, LetsEncrypt aren't even issuing certificates to my deployment or domain.

Thus I tried to follow a different guide which is as follows -> [istio-gateway-tls-setup](https://docs.flagger.app/install/flagger-install-on-google-cloud#istio-gateway-tls-setup). Here I managed to get LetsEncrypt issue a certificate for my domain, but when I tried to test it out with openssl or other online ssl checkers, it says that I still aren't communicating securely.

Below are the results when I try describe the configurations of my certificates, issuer & gateway:

**Certificate: kubectl -n istio-system describe certificate istio-gateway**
[image]

**Issuer:  kubectl -n istio-system describe issuer letsencrypt-prod**
[image]

**Gateway: kubectl -n istio-system describe gateway istio-gateway**
[image]

While here's the dry-run results for my `helm install <tenant>`

```
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/cjcabero/projects/aqt-ott-msging-dev/gke-setup/helmchart

NAME: tenanta
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Feb 17 21:15:08 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: pending-install
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
{}

COMPUTED VALUES:
frontend:
  image:
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    repository: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes
    tag: "1.8"
  ports:
    containerPort: 8080
  service:
    name: http
    port: 80
    type: ClusterIP

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:
---
# Source: helmchart/templates/namespace.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: tenanta
  labels:
    istio-injection: enabled
---
# Source: helmchart/templates/frontend-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: tenanta
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: frontend
---
# Source: helmchart/templates/frontend-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: tenanta
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: MESSAGE
          value: Hello tenanta
---
# Source: helmchart/templates/virtualservice.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tenanta-frontend-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - tenanta.cjcabero.dev
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend.tenanta.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

I don't understand how come even though LetsEncrypt seem to be able issue the certificate for my domain, it still aren't communicating securely.

Google Domains even managed to find that a certificate was issued in the domain in it's [Transparency Report](https://transparencyreport.google.com/https/certificates?cert_search=include_subdomains:true;domain:cjcabero.dev&hl=en-US).

Anyway, I'm not sure if this could help, but I also tried the check the domain with an online ssl checker and here are the results -> [https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=cjcabero.dev](https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?i=32a4bcdc-f254-4c30-abcb-7ba40aa2f435).

By the way I did use [Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview) which results with Istio v1.4.10 & Kubernetes v1.18.15-gke.1100.